# React native maps not getting added to project

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and trying to add google maps to my project.

```
Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-maps from C:\...\MapSearch.js:
  react-native-maps could not be found within the project or in these directories:
    node_modules
```

Used dependency: `npm install react-native-maps --save`

Links followed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps

My error is as follows:

```
code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: appname@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.0 || < 17.0" from react-native-maps@0.28.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-maps
npm ERR!     react-native-maps@"^0.28.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (react-native, react-native-web)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">=16.5.1" from react-native-web@0.11.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     peer react-native-web@"^0.11" from react-native-maps@0.28.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-maps
npm ERR! 

  react-native-maps@"^0.28.0" from the root project
```

Comment: Confirm you build app again after installing new packages

Comment: Yes after installing new packages I build an app

Comment: I think the installation or build may be not complete and failed,  Try install again then build again  `npx react-native run-android` then start bundle `npx react-native start`

Comment: @AhmedGaber running npx react-native start
Gives below 
warn Package react-native-maps has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'react-native-maps\package.json'

Answer (score 0):

try to Delete **npm_modules** folder and reinstall all node modules

Comment: is there any command to delete node_modules or simply deleting that folder

Comment: delete folder directly